# Is there a way to make a scrolling marquee on a SVG path using HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like to make an effect as seen [here](https://getlupii.com/) or in the main menu of [colin mcrae rally 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI6ppRGxGsY).

I would like to generate a `path` and then have text inside it that moves along the path and wraps around to the start as the the letters go off on end.

Looking at the html of the first example I saw that JS was used to make it but I'd like to avoid that if possible but that's not necessary.

Apologies since this is quite an open ended question with no actual code of my own to show, since this might be a problem of not knowing the correct search terms to get the correct resources I need to create this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) and [SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL).

I made two identical texts that are animated along the path. It is not perfect aligned - that is your task.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
        text { font-size: 8px }
    </style>

    <symbol id="s1">
        <path id="p1" d="M 0,0 C 5,10 5,40 20,40 35,40 60,55 60,70 60,85 100,100 100,100" />
    </symbol>

    <use href="#s1" stroke="silver" stroke-width="10" fill="none" />

    <text dominant-baseline="middle">
        <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="100%">
            Text 1, text 2, text 3, text 3, text 4
        <animate
        attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-100%"
        dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </textPath>
    </text>

    <text dominant-baseline="middle">
        <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="100%">
            Text 1, text 2, text 3, text 3, text 4
        <animate
        attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-100%"
        dur="10s" begin="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </textPath>
    </text>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I include my own path, the text disappears after a certain point.
`<path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="blue" d="M202 168c-52-20-46 15-98 3-53-11-59-16-48-22s14-23 2-24c-11 0-71-26-36-23s155 31 161 15c7-15-132-25-107-32 24-7 20-13 53-9 33 3 49 1 34-4-15-6-68-16-49-16 19-1 40-6 56-1l14 4" />   
`

Comment: @datapagan I have tested your path and I can see the problem, but I'm not able to explain why. I updated my answer with a better version. Now the text flows in the right direction, so that you can read it... And the difference between the tow texts is the begin attribute on the second. Also I inserted the path in a symbol element so that is can be used as a background to the text.